# meta multiple operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, metaprogramming, parameterization

The question is if I can find a way to make a parametrized overloading of an operator i.e. instead of

```
template <class T>
class A
{
   private:
       T m_var;
   public:
       operator T () const { return m_var; }
       const A operator+ ( const A& r_var ) const { return m_var + r_var; }
       const A operator- ( const A& r_var ) const { return m_var - r_var; }
       const A operator* ( const A& r_var ) const { return m_var * r_var; }
       const A operator/ ( const A& r_var ) const { return m_var / r_var; }
   ...........
}
```

to have something like this

```
template <class T>
class A
{
   private:
       T m_var;
   public:
       operator T () const { return m_var; }
       const A operator 'X' ( const A& r_var ) const { return m_var 'X' r_var; }

   ...........
}
```

where 'X' will take values +, -, *, /, and in this way to avoid repetition of the same pattern code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How could it be done using macro? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check out [boost::operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/operators.htm). It requires += and *= to be defined by you. The rest(+,-,*,/,-=,/=) are defined by the library. It also works for binary operators.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible within templates. You will need to write a macro.

Also, you should not return a const rvalue, because it's perfectly legal to call non-const methods on rvalues of class type.